# Is it possible to instantiate multiple instances of a class through a single classmethod call?

Tags: python

So I've used python as a functional language for a while but I'm trying to do thing "right" and use classes now... and falling down. I'm trying to write a classmethod that can instantiate multiple members of the class (use case is load rows from SQLAlchemy.) I'd like to just be able to call the classmethod and have it return a status code (success/failure) rather than returning a list of objects. Then to access the objects I'll iterate through the class. Here's my code so far (which fails to iterate when I use the classmethod, works fine when I use the normal constructor.) Am I way off-base/crazy here? What's the "pythonic" way to do this? Any help is appreciated and thank you.

```
class KeepRefs(object):
    __refs__ = defaultdict(list)
    def __init__(self):
        self.__refs__[self.__class__].append(weakref.ref(self))

    @classmethod
    def get_instances(cls):
        for inst_ref in cls.__refs__[cls]:
            inst = inst_ref()
            if inst is not None:
                yield inst

class Credentials(KeepRefs):

    def __init__(self,name, username, password):
        super(Credentials, self).__init__()
        self.name=name
        self.username=username
        self.password=password

    @classmethod
    def loadcreds(cls):
        Credentials('customer1','bob','password')
        return True


success = Credentials.loadcreds()
for i in Credentials.get_instances():
    print (i.name)
```

Comment: "I'd like to just be able to call the classmethod and have it return a status code (success/failure) " Definitely not Pythonic.

Comment: Don't return a list (or a status code), return a generator that you can iterate over to retrieve the results one by one. Whatever you were trying to achieve with your approach, this will do it better. A generator (google "python yield") is basically a lazy function; you could have one that generates an infinite-length list, and everything will work fine (as long as your program knows to stop reading eventually).

Comment: Yeah the status code part was actually an after thought, my real goal here was to keep the class self contained and able to load itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functional languages have certain advantages, and you are going too far the other way in your exploration of the procedural style. Global variables and class variable have their place, but what will happen if you need to fire off *two* SQAlchemy queries and consume the results in parallels? The second query will stomp over the class attributes that the first one still needs, is what. Using an object attribute (instance attribute) solves the problem, since each result contains its own handle.

If your concern is to avoid pre-fetching the array of results, you are in luck because Python offers the perfect solution: [Generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), which are basically lazy functions. They are so nicely integrated in Python, I bet you didn't know you've been using them with every for-loop you write.

Answer (score 1):

In your own words - yes, you are off-base and crazy :)

Status-Codes are a thing of C, not languages with proper exception semantics as Python. Modifying global state is a sure recipe for disaster. So - don't do it. Return a list of objects. Throw an exception if something disastrous happens, and just return an empty list if there happen to be no objects. This allows the client code to just do

```
for item in Thingies.load_thingies():
     ... # this won't do anything if load_thingies gave us an empty list
```

without having to painstakingly check something before using it.

Comment: Hehe that's fair. To be clear though the status code was an afterthought, the real goal was to keep the class self contained and able to load itself without having to track the instances externally. It seems like that's not the way forward though. :-) Thanks for the help!